# Aligning a row of plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, alignment

I have used the following code to obtain 5 subplots,

```
pylab.subplot(231)
pylab.scatter(x_a, y_a, color='darkorange')
make_diagonal(x_a, y_a)

pylab.subplot(232)
pylab.scatter(x_b, y_b, color='g')
make_diagonal(x_b, y_b)

pylab.subplot(233)
pylab.scatter(x_c, y_c, color='blue')
make_diagonal(x_c, y_c)

pylab.subplot(234)
pylab.scatter(x_d, y_d, color='r')
make_diagonal(x_d, y_d)

pylab.subplot(235)
pylab.scatter(x_e, y_e, color='purple')
make_diagonal(x_e, y_e)

plt.show()
```

The following figure was obtained,

[image]

I want to center align the last row of subplots. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal working answer for you using `gridspec`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

# Define the plots here
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 6)
gs.update(wspace=0.5)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, :2], )
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 2:4])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 4:], )
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 1:3])
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 3:5])

# Plot your data here
ax1.plot(x,y, 'darkorange')
ax2.plot(x,y, 'g')
ax3.plot(x,y, 'b')
ax4.plot(x,y,'r')
ax5.plot(x,y,'purple')
```

**Output**

[image]